# Excel WBA UDF to manipulate string doesn't work

Tags: string, excel, vba, udf

My UDF in VBA is complaining about invalid qualifier and I don't understand why.

[image]

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBA string does not have a Chars() modifier. use MID(Trans,i,1) instead